# How to fetch/retrieve files from AWS Glacier using PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am trying to fetch/retrieve files stored on AWS Glacier using PHP. But I am not able to find any method to do so.

What I want is just fetch/retrieve from AWS Glacier using PHP. If anyone have idea about it then please suggest me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As per [example from github](https://github.com/pihish/amazon_glacier/blob/master/download_4.php) you can retrieve a file using the following

```
// Use the us-west-2 region and latest version of each client.
$sharedConfig = [
    'region'  => 'us-west-2',
    'version' => 'latest'
];

// Create an SDK class used to share configuration across clients.
$sdk = new Aws\Sdk($sharedConfig);

// Create an Amazon Glacier client using the shared configuration data.
$client = $sdk-> createGlacier();

//Download our archive from Amazon to our server
$result = $aws->getJobOutput(array(
    'vaultName' => '<YOUR VAULT>',  //The name of the vault
    'jobId' => 'XXXX'  //supply the unique ID of the job that retrieved the archive 
));

$data = $result->get('body');  //Sets the file data to a variable
$description = $result->get('archiveDescription');  //Sets file description to a variable

//deletes the temp file on our server if it exists
if(file_exists("files/temp")){
    unlink("files/temp");
}

$filepath = "files/temp";  
$fp = fopen($filepath, "w");  //creates a new file temp file on our web server
fwrite($fp, $data);  //write the data in our variable to our temp file

//Your archive is now ready for download on your web server
```

You can review [PHP Glacier ref documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-glacier-2012-06-01.html) for more details